# Getting column index out of range, 0 < 1

Tags: openjpa

I am using OpenJPA 2.2.0 and when I am executing a select statement I am getting "Column index out of range, 0 < 1" error.

```
EntityManager entityMgrObj = emf.getEntityManager();

entityMgrObj.clear();

Query query = entityMgrObj.createNativeQuery("select * from company_user where user_id = 1001);

List<CompanyUserDO> companyUserDOObj = null;

try {
    companyUserDOObj = query.getResultList();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

When the query.getResultList() executes I get "Column index out of range, 0 < 1" error. Can somebody let me know what is wrong in the above code?

**@UPDATE**

When I do not catch the exception following stack is printed on the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.
FailedObject: select * from company_user where user_id=1001 [java.lang.String]
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4918)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4878)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:118)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:70)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.GenericResultObjectProvider.handleCheckedException(GenericResultObjectProvider.java:125)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:40)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1251)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
at zumigo.geofence.test.dalTest.main(dalTest.java:62)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:812)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:121)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.getString(DBDictionary.java:886)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.ResultSetResult.getStringInternal(ResultSetResult.java:474)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.getString(AbstractResult.java:767)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StringFieldStrategy.getPrimaryKeyValue(StringFieldStrategy.java:217)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.getObjectId(ClassMapping.java:188)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.getObjectId(ClassMapping.java:147)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1002)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.GenericResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(GenericResultObjectProvider.java:93)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36)
... 8 more
```

**@UPDATE 2**
After searching and debugging it was found that the persistence.xml file was pointing to an old database hence it was giving the above mentioned error.

Changed the database URL and the application is working fine.  :)

Comment: For me is the "*": I don't know OpenJPA, but my two cents are that it tries to fetch column index through column name, but in this case it can't and return 0, which is a non valid value. Sorry if this doesn't help you but I'm not even a real developer :D

Comment: I do not think that is the case as I am able to execute following query `select * from user where username like xxx and password like yyy`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all, but you seem to use a persistence context (since you use the clear method). Did you try to use the

```
createQuery
```

method instead of the

```
createNativeQuery
```

one? It'll use the JPA persistence context, it works on my Java EE project. 
Good luck.

Comment: I want to use Native SQL query. The `createQuery` is for query based on "JAVA Persistence Query Language". Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But both really look alike (especially for such an easy query)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that column index in jdbc is computed from 1. And it's different from array, which is computed from 0.

Comment: Can you improve this answer by a) linking to a reference that agrees with your statement, and perhaps b) adding code that shows how to actually fix the OP's problem?

Answer (score -1):

I also had that problem. You can change

```
companyUserDOObj = query.getResultList();
```

to

```
companyUserDOObj.addAll(query.getResultList());
```